# Ubuntu 14.04 clear list of recent files in Dash

Tags: unity, 14.04, unity-dash

How to disable or clear list of recent files in Ubuntu Unity Dash? I can find many ways to do so in older version of Ubuntu but none of them work in 14.04.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to clear usage data from the dash you can open **Security & Privacy**:
[image: open security and privacy from dash]

Then select `Clear Usage Data` and select the desired time frame:
[image: Clear usage data]

You can also disable all monitoring of files from this configuration menu or deselect specific file-types on the left side.

Comment: not work! Ubuntu 16 keeps adding videos in the Recent list evens after exclude Videos, Movies folder,  Video player app

Answer (score 0):

The best cleaner I know for Ubuntu is Bleachbit install and execute with the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit

sudo bleachbit
```